# SendGrid Transaction Template Custom Parameter c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid

Im using asp mvc core with the Sendgrid nuget package installed

I can successfully create/send/receive a plain text email. However im now attempting to use a transnational template i created in my sendgrid account to pass custom values for replacing within the template.

when i run the following i receive a bad request error in the response variable:

```
        public async Task<Response> SendTemplateAsync(string to, string toName, string subject, string plainTextContent, string htmlContent, string templateId, IEnumerable<IFormFile> attachments = null)
    {
        var msg = new SendGridMessage
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(_sendGridSettings.EmailFrom, _sendGridSettings.EmailFromName),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = plainTextContent,
            HtmlContent = htmlContent,
            TemplateId = templateId
        };
        msg.AddSubstitution("-NAME-", toName.ToString());
        msg.AddSubstitution("-UREF-", "ABC 123".ToString());

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(to, toName));

        var response = await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);

        return response;
    }
```

i seem unable to access any meaningful error message, nothing in the console etc. The above code works when i remove the "msg.AddSubstitution" and template references.

I read a number of examples that all seem to suggest what i am doing is right. Could someone also explain the difference between Substitution and custom args

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a BadRequest response until I changed my TemplateId to be the cryptic ID assigned by the system rather than my human-readable Version Name.